# GNU time(1) reports wrong I/O count

Tags: python, time, gnu

on fedora 16, running time(1) on a small program that just does 10 writes of 1024 bytes to a file, reports "24 outputs". I was expecting the I/O count to be 10. Note that if i run strace on the program I can see the 10 write() calls. 
So what is the I/O count as reported by time(1)?
thanks a lot

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import pdb

SIZE_IO=1024
IONB=10

def test1(file):
    #pdb.set_trace()
    buffer= '\x01' * SIZE_IO
    fd = os.open(file, os.O_CREAT|os.O_RDWR, 0777)
    for ix in range(IONB):
        len = os.write(fd, buffer)
        print len
    os.close(fd)
    return 1

if name__== "__main":
    test1("ttt.txt")
    print 'ok'
```

Comment: Please show us the command you ran as well as the "small program".

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python    
import os

SIZE_IO=1024
IONB=10
def test1(file):
        #pdb.set_trace()
        buffer= '\x01' * SIZE_IO
        fd = os.open (file, os.O_CREAT|os.O_RDWR, 0777)
        for ix in range(IONB):
                len = os.write(fd, buffer)
        os.close(fd)
        return 1
if __name__== "__main__":
        test1("ttt.txt")
        print 'ok'

Comment: And the `time` command you used, with output?  Also, please verify my formatting.

Comment: /usr/bin/time ./template.py 0.10user 0.02system 0:00.13elapsed 98%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4700maxresident)k
0inputs+24outputs (0major+1308minor)pagefaults 0swaps

Comment: I have no idea how to format that.  Please put it in your question.

Comment: There's a section on the accuracy in the `time(1)` manpage: "       The  `%I' and `%O' values are allegedly only `real' input and output and do not include those supplied by caching devices.  The meaning
       of `real' I/O reported by `%I' and `%O' may be muddled for workstations, especially diskless ones."

Answer (score 2):

Isn't each print going to cause a write as well?

Comment: Hi, removing the print() has no impact..count stays the same

Answer (score 0):

excerpt from the *ACCURACY* section in `time(1)` manpage :

> The  '%I' and '%O' values are allegedly only 'real' input and output
>   and do not include those supplied by caching devices.  The meaning
>   of 'real' I/O reported by '%I' and '%O' may be muddled for workstations,
>   especially diskless ones.